# Replacing multiple while keeping a number that changes the same on each line

Tags: replace

i have a list like 
1. md (1)
2. md (2)
3. ....
4. md (10)
it goes on line that for a while but i want to make it 
md line (1)
.... 
 
md line (10) and so on. 
 can i use the replace feature on notepad++ to do this? like "find" md (put some kind of placeholder here that will find all the numbers but keep them the same) and replace" with md line (same place holder). I've tried using a number sign as a place holder but it didn't work. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
^([0-9]+. md)
```

with

```
md line
```

Pattern anchored to the beginning of a line via `^`, one or more digits, followed by a period, a space and `md`.